# POI setting Cell Background to a Custom Hex Color

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to set the Cell Background to a Custom Hex Color, when i try cs.setFillForegroundColor(color); java pops up an error
when i replace it by cs.setFillForegroundColor(color.getIndex()); the background shows a black background color.

Did they update java poi concerning this?: cs.setFillForegroundColor(color); 
I tried setfillbackgroundColor also the same result appears. Please help

```
        String rgbS = "E4DFEC";
        byte[] rgbB = Hex.decodeHex(rgbS); // get byte array from hex string
        XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(rgbB, null);
        cs.setFillForegroundColor(color.getIndex());
```

Comment: use the `IndexedColors` enum. Custom colors are not really supported

Comment: What is `cs` in your case? If it is a `XSSFCellStyle`, then [XSSFCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(XSSFColor color)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor-) will work.

Comment: No it is cellStyle only

Comment: A `CellStyle` cannot work with a `XSSFColor`. Only `XSSFCellStyle` can. `CellStyle` only works using indexed colors. And `XSSFColor`s are not indexed until now.